# Is it possible to install qgis plugin in a specific non default directory?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Is it possible to install a plugin to a specific directory e.g. `D:\folder` instead of the default one `.qgis\python\plugin`?

Furthermore, can QGIS access plugins from different directories and folders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> use plugins from various directions

Yes by setting `set QGIS_PLUGINPATH`

E.g

```
set QGIS_PLUGINPATH=C:\Temp
```

Will load plugins from C:\Temp\

> Is it possible to install plugin in specific

You can if you move you whole qgis home directory by starting qgis with the `--configpath` swtich.